# Eclipse Oxygen Release (4.7.0) Remote Debug Glassfish NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, remote-debugging

Eclipse Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
- OS: Win7
- jdk1.8.0_131
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 (build 43) in a VM
- OS: Ubuntu
- Started with "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009"

I want using the debugging with "Remote Java Application", but i get this error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2017-08-21 14:18:27.530
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching OutletResource".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path.<init>(Path.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceRoot.getProject(WorkspaceRoot.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIDebugTarget.getProjectOfExternalFolder(JDIDebugTarget.java:1557)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIDebugTarget.addReferencedProjects(JDIDebugTarget.java:1508)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIDebugTarget.collectReferencedJavaProjects(JDIDebugTarget.java:1481)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIDebugTarget.prepareBreakpointsSearchScope(JDIDebugTarget.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIDebugTarget.<init>(JDIDebugTarget.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core.JDIDebugModel$1.run(JDIDebugModel.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core.JDIDebugModel.newDebugTarget(JDIDebugModel.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core.JDIDebugModel.newDebugTarget(JDIDebugModel.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.SocketAttachConnector.connect(SocketAttachConnector.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.JavaRemoteApplicationLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(JavaRemoteApplicationLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Can someone help? Thank you, Dirk

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
Under PROJECT -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries
A empty folder (like "VM_HOME - U:\") make this Exception. Eclipse versions deeper then Oxygen works with this Properties.